How do I place a node that is horizontally aligned with one node, and is vertically aligned with the middle of two nodes in above?
I have a fifth node I wish to align with three other nodes. The current nodes are aligned like
 A         B         C
 D

I wish to place node E as such:
 A         B         C
 D              E

where E is aligned horizontally with D, and vertically in the middle of B and C.
I can't work out how to do this. These are all io shapes in a flowchart, with io defined as
 io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
    trapezium stretches=true

I know I can align E with D and B by using
 \node[io](E) at (D-|B) {E};

I know I can align E below B and C using
 \node[io, below = 1.5 cm of $(B)!0.5!(C)$](E){E};

I can't work out how to do both.
This doesn't seem to work:
 \node[io](E) at (D -| ($(B)!0.5!(C)$)) {E};

I get the errors
 Package pgf Error: No shape named `($(B' is known. \node[io](E) at (D -| ($(B)
 Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text. ...ode[io](E) at (D -| ($(B)!
 Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. ...ode[io](E) at (D -| ($(B)!
 Missing $ inserted. \end{tikzpicture}

I also attempted it without using the brackets around the B and C specification:
 \node[io](E) at (D -| $(B)!0.5!(C)$) {E};

and I get the following errors:
 Package tikz Error: + or - expected. \node[io](E) at (D -| $(B)
 Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text. \node[io](E) at (D -| $(B)!
 Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. \node[io](E) at (D -| $(B)!
 Missing $ inserted. \end{tikzpicture}

A, B, C, and D are all defined before E.
 \node[io](B){B}; 
 \node[io, left = 1.8cm of B](A){A};
 \node[io, right = 1.8cm of B](C){C};
 \node[io, below = 1cm of A](D){D};

In my flowchart, the text in each node varies in length, with some having an extra row in the trapezium. The reason I am trying to do the -| alignment with E is to compensate for the varying trapezium heights.
How do I get my horizontal and vertical alignment for E?
Edit: code that renders E, but is placed between B and C and not below on the line with D.
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                                   %write flowcharts etc
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, chains, fit, backgrounds, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, calligraphy, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            font=\scriptsize,
            startstop/.style = {rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum  height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
            io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
            trapezium stretches=true,
            process/.style = {rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,  text centered, draw=black},
            decision/.style = {diamond, text width=2cm, minimum height=.5cm, text centered, draw=black},
            arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}]
    \node[io](B){B}; 
    \node[io, left = 1.8cm of B](A){A};
    \node[io, right = 1.8cm of B](C){C};
    \node[process, below = 1cm of A](D){D};
    \node[io](E) at  ($(B)!0.5!(C)$ |-D ) {E};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{flowchart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


Please post a complete minimal example. This is much more useful than code snippets. You can try reversal e.g. ($...$ |- node) rather than (node -| $...$) or (... -| {$...$}). But sometimes it's easier to just get a coordinate first.

I didn't think a full code snippet was necessary in this case, given the two examples of different definitions, and I figured some type of combination of the two was needed. I tried the reversal and I get it positioned mid-way between B and C. The part from |- onwards is now being ignored, although I do have a node showing. No error message, it renders.

If you shared the code which renders but gives the wrong result, I would take a look.

I just want E to be on the same horizontal as D, and positioned exactly in the middle of B and C. I'm still drawing the flowchart and am likely to need to bring D over more to the middle. And if I shift D over, I then have to reestimate the cm between B and C. Hence why I would like to have a relative definition.

Alas, the calc and perpendicular nomenclatures are not compatible.  You will probably need to do it in two steps: \coordinate (BC) at ($B!0.5!C$); (D-|BC).

If you keep your original idea, which uses the vertical/horizontal operation |-, all you have to do is use an auxiliary coordinate.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                                   %write flowcharts etc
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, chains, fit, backgrounds, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, calligraphy, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            font=\scriptsize,
            startstop/.style = {rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum  height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
            io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
            trapezium stretches=true,
            process/.style = {rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,  text centered, draw=black},
            decision/.style = {diamond, text width=2cm, minimum height=.5cm, text centered, draw=black},
            arrow/.style={thick, -stealth}]
    \node[io](B){B}; 
    \node[io, left = 1.8cm of B](A){A};
    \node[io, right = 1.8cm of B](C){C};
    \node[process, below = 1cm of A](D){D};
    \coordinate (aux) at ($(B)!0.5!(C)$);
    \node[io](E) at  (aux |- D) {E};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{flowchart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



Such a simple solution I missed entirely because I was so sure that I could combine the calc and perpendicular code in the same node.

You could position the either below left=of C or below right=of B:
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}                                   %write flowcharts etc
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, chains, fit, backgrounds, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, calligraphy, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            font=\scriptsize,
            startstop/.style = {rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum  height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
            io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
            trapezium stretches=true,
            process/.style = {rectangle, text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,  text centered, draw=black},
            decision/.style = {diamond, text width=2cm, minimum height=.5cm, text centered, draw=black},
            arrow/.style={thick, -stealth},
            node distance=1cm and 1.8cm
            ]
    \node[io](B){B}; 
    \node[io, left=of B](A){A};
    \node[io, right=of B](C){C};
    \node[process, below=of A](D){D};
    \node[io,below left=of C](E) {E};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{flowchart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



If A, B, and C have different numbers of rows, will this still work?

As long as you don't manually change their spacing (or if you do so, also adjust the spacing of E), then this should work regardless of how many nodes you have.
